# Flood fill algorithm for bucket tool in P5.js electron paint application

Tags: javascript, p5.js, flood-fill

I'm trying to create a bucket tool for my paint application made with electron.js and P5.js for the canvas stuff. everytime a user clicks on the canvas and his `mode` variable is equal to "fill", it calls the floodFill function. i tried to implement the algorithm from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Pseudocode (Stack-based recursive implementation (four-way)), but i have a problem - i'm reaching maximum call stack.
the way i render everything to the screen is i have an array called `drawing` and there are constructor functions for the types of things you can draw (Circle, Square) so i created a Pixel constructor function so that i can render it everytime, i cannot call `updatePixels()` because i render everything every frame with the `draw()` function.
this is my floodFill function:

```
function floodFill(x, y, target_col, replace_col) {
   if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x <= width && y <= height) {
        let index = (x + y * width) * 4;
        if (target_col === replace_col) {
            return;
        } else if (
            pixels[index] !== target_col.levels[0] &&
            pixels[index + 1] !== target_col.levels[1] &&
            pixels[index + 2] !== target_col.levels[2] &&
            pixels[index + 3] !== target_col.levels[3]
        ) {
            return;
        } else {
            drawing.push(new Pixel(x, y, replace_col));
            floodFill(x, y - 1, target_col, replace_col);
            floodFill(x, y + 1, target_col, replace_col);
            floodFill(x - 1, y, target_col, replace_col);
            floodFill(x + 1, y, target_col, replace_col);
        }
    }
}
```

this is how i call the function:

```
if (mode === "fill") {
    loadPixels();
    let index = (mouseX + mouseY * width) * 4;

    // target_color = what the user wants to replace
    let target_color = color(
        pixels[index],
        pixels[index + 1],
        pixels[index + 2],
        pixels[index + 3]
    );
   // replacement_color = the color that will be instead of the target_color
   let replacement_color = color(current_color);
    floodFill(mouseX, mouseY, target_color, replacement_color);
}
```

by the way in the `floodFill` function in the `else if` i used this technique because simply doing `color(pixels[index], pixels[index + 1], pixels[index + 2], pixels[index + 3]) !== target_col` didn't work

EDIT: 
I realized i had an error with the floodFill function, my `else if` is almost never true because it also tries to check if the alphas are not equal and they are almost always 255. so i added to the else if this:

```
else if (
     (pixels[index] !== target_col.levels[0] &&
         pixels[index + 1] !== target_col.levels[1] &&
        pixels[index + 2] !== target_col.levels[2]) ||
    pixels[index + 3] !== target_col.levels[3]
 ) {
```

now what happens is if i try to fill something it draws a straight line up until it reaches the other color, but then reaches maximum stack size,
example:
[image: paint]
this is probably because in the `floodFill` function the first recursive call i make is to `y - 1` (up). 
I would love to hear more suggestions

ANOTHER EDIT:
i figured out that in the `floodFill` in the recursive section im calling it with `y - 1` then with `y + 1` which makes no sense because it goes up and then down means it stays at the same pixel, so i edited it to be like this:

```
floodFill(x, y - 1, target_col, replace_col);
floodFill(x - 1, y, target_col, replace_col);
floodFill(x, y + 1, target_col, replace_col);
floodFill(x + 1, y, target_col, replace_col);
```

now it shows up like this:
[image: paint]

Answer (score 2):

here's a fill example in p5.js.

draw a closed shape in the cavas, and then shift-click inside it.

```js
var stack = [];
var oldColor;
var fillColor


function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  noSmooth();
  fillColor = color(0, 255, 0);
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {

  function matches(c, x, y) {
    return JSON.stringify(get(x, y)) === JSON.stringify(c);
  }

  if (!stack.length) return;

  let p = stack.pop();
  let x1 = p.x, y = p.y;
  while (x1 > 0 && matches(oldColor, x1 - 1, y))
    x1--;

  let spanAbove = false, spanBelow = false;

  for (let x2 = x1 + 1; x2 < width && matches(oldColor, x2, y); ++x2) {
    set(x2, y, fillColor);

    if (y > 0 && spanAbove !== matches(oldColor, x2, y - 1)) {
      if (!spanAbove)
        stack.push({ x: x2, y: y - 1 });
      spanAbove = !spanAbove;
    }
    if (y < height - 1 && spanBelow !== matches(oldColor, x2, y + 1)) {
      if (!spanBelow)
        stack.push({ x: x2, y: y + 1 });
      spanBelow = !spanBelow;
    }
  }

  updatePixels();
}

function mouseDragged() {
  if (keyIsDown(SHIFT)) return;
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(2);
  line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
}

function mouseClicked() {
  if (keyIsDown(SHIFT)) {
    oldColor = get(mouseX, mouseY);
    loadPixels();
    stack = [];
    stack.push({ x: mouseX, y: mouseY });
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: black;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```